# TypeError: and how do I pre process my data?

Tags: python, gensim

https://pastecord.com/yfabaficup.sql

Im getting this type error preprocessing my data.
tried searching the whole google and stack overflow
cannot find answer please help. Im using pandas and gensim for this task thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What exactly do want to achieve apply function this to all columns?

Comment: What kind of data do you have - descriptively, not as an image of a fragment? Where did it come from? What do you want to do with it, and why is the Gensim `simple_preprocess()` function of interest to you?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps for an example:

```
import pandas as pd
data={"Text1":["The DNA complexation and condensation properties","Three proteins namely protective antigen PA edition","Lecithin retinol acyltransferase LRAT catalyze"],"ID":range(3)}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df["Split_Text"]=df["Text1"].apply(lambda x: simple_preprocess(str(x))) # You can apply this to multiple column if needed.
```